# Form Recognizer Model that has been trained with label not able to be detected in MS Flow

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I have created and trained a Form Recognizer Model using sample labeling tool. However, I am not able to Get Model via MS Flow's Form Recognizer. I was able to Get Model via Form Recognizer API. Hence, the model exists but not able to be pulled by MS Flow's Form Recognizer.

Can you please advise how I can have this model that has been labeled to be pulled into MS Flow's Form Recognizer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Flow Form Recognizer connector supports Form Recognizer v1 API and is not yet updated to the v2 API, hence it can't pull the model created with the v2 Train with labels feature. Please create a custom connector in flow that calls the REST API of v2 directly.